# Extjs grid cell editor jumps away from cell

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally, appsdk2

Im having this issue in Extjs grid editing. When I tab from a dropdown editor to a textarea editor, the textarea editor jumps down the screen, away from the cell I should be editing: [image]

I have no idea how to fix this. It only happens 1/2 of the time, so I believe there is some race condition, but Im not sure. Ive spent a lot of time debugging and stepping through the editing code and the textarea starts out in the grid cell, but some event fires or something and it then moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, but I don't think there is a good solution to it. When I complete the edit by clicking tab, new value is put in the grid cell.

The grid row height might change, which will cause the grid viewport size to change (since i am not using a scroll bar.. the grid height grows and shrinks dynamically).

The grid is in an iframe, and i attached a listener to the grid resize event to change the iframe height to be the size of the grid height, this in turn caused floating elements (such as a cell editor) to be repositioned.

So my problem is that i want the iframe to grow with the grid, which grows and shrinks (by a few pixels) as cells get edited. But this causes the floating element to jump.